# How to display tags in jekyll and get the tag to click through to all relevant collection posts

Tags: tags, jekyll

I am looking to display all the tags from my collection posts in a sidebar, and have each tag click through to all the relevant posts. I would also like to display the number of times the tag has been used like this:

tag_name (10)

This is what I have currently which has got all the tags as a list but I cant figure out how to get the tag to click through to all relevant pages and also display the size.

```
<ul class="">
    {% assign tags =  site.vacancies | map: 'tags' | join: ','  | split: ',' | uniq %}
     {% for tag in tags %}
        <li class="text-capitalize">
            <a href="{{ tag }}" class="sidebar-tag">{{ tag }}</a>
        </li>
     {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, retrieve all tags into an list by using `site.tags` provide by [Jekyll Variables](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/)

```html
{% capture site_tags %}{% for tag in site.tags %}{{ tag | first }}{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}{% endfor %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign tags_list = site_tags | split:',' | sort_natural %}
```

Secondly, get a link for each Tag with its post count correspondingly

```html
<ul>
  {% for item in (0..site.tags.size) %}{% unless forloop.last %}
    {% capture this_word %}{{ tags_list[item] | strip_newlines }}{% endcapture %}
    <li><a href="#{{ this_word}}" class="tag"><span class="tag-name">{{ this_word }}</span> <span class="count">{{ site.tags[this_word].size }}</span></a></li>
  {% endunless %}{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Thirdly, show each tag's name and its posts' name and date.

```html
{% for item in (0..site.tags.size) %}{% unless forloop.last %}
  {% capture this_word %}{{ tags_list[item] | strip_newlines }}{% endcapture %}
    <article id="{{ this_word }}">
    <h2 class="tag-heading tag-name">{{ this_word }}</h2>
        <ul>
    {% for post in site.tags[this_word] %}{% if post.title != null %}
      <li><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}" >{{ post.date | date: '%m/%d/%Y' }} ---- {{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}{% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </article>
{% endunless %}{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

So there's a way to do it by creating an array of tags while iterating through posts in the collection and using lots of liquid... and I decided to do my own workaround.

I have a master list of all the tags that I use stored in `/_data/tagList.yml`. Each tag has a name and slug, and you can add more fields like a description if you want to. I iterate through the data in `tagList`, and for each tag have a link to a dedicated page that lists all the posts that contain that tag.

If you followed the [Jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#categories-and-tags) and used `tags` in the front matter and you are consistent in naming your tags, then you can use the `site.tags[tag.name] | size` filter to get a count on how many posts have that tag.

Drawbacks of this workaround are:

- you need to update `tagList.yml` any time you make a new tag
- you need to make a new page for that tag (not a big deal since you can just copy/paste code from other tag pages and just change the tag you're looking for)
- you need to ensure you are consistent in naming and using tags

```
//   /_data/tagList.yml
- name: Coding
  slug: coding

- name: UnpopularOpinion
  slug: unpopular-opinion
```

```
//   /_posts/2019-01-01-example.html
---
tags: [Coding, UnpopularOpinion]
---
```

```
//   /blog/tags.html
{% for tag in site.data.tagList %}
    <div>
        <h2><a href="/blog/tags/{{tag.slug}}.html">{{tag.name}}</a></h2>
        {% assign postCount = site.tags[tag.name] | size %}
        <em>
            {% if postCount == 1 %}
                {{postCount}} post
            {% else %}
                {{postCount}} posts
            {% endif %}
        </em>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

```
//   /blog/tags/coding.html
{% assign numPosts = site.tags.Coding | size %}
{% if numPosts == 0 %}
    <p>No posts have this tag...yet.</p>
{% endif %}

{% for post in site.tags.Coding %}
    ...code to display a post...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This kinda works :D I now have a decent list of the tags and i have managed to get the tags to click through to a page.  the count feature doesnt work...I am getting zero??

Comment: You can use `{{ postCount }}` right before the `<em`> to output the value of `postCount`. If it's always 0, then either `site.tags` or the `tag.name` is wrong. So, make sure the front matter in posts is using the `tags` field and that the names are exactly the same. Also forgot to mention that `tags` should have a comma-delimited array. `tags: [Coding, UnpopularOpinion]`. That might also help

Comment: Updated the answer to be more fleshed out. Hopefully solves your bug